# Is there a prime of the form $\ (9n)!+n!+1\ $?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, examples-counterexamples

*See also MathOverflow: [Why am I unable to find primes of the form $(9n)!+n!+1$?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/348005/129831)*

In a project, I search primes of the form $$(kn)!+n!+1$$ with positive integers $\ k,n\ $. The smallest $\ k\ $ for which I still know no prime is $\ k=9\ $.

For $$k=1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$$ the numbers $$n=1,3,605,185,850,7,11,120$$ are respective the smallest $n$ for which we get a prime, except possibly for $n = 605, 850$, in which case we just know we get a probable prime (the rest is proven to be prime according to [FactorDB](http://factordb.com/))

> Is there a prime of the form $$(9n)!+n!+1$$ with positive integer $\ n\ $ ?

Chances should be good because such a number cannot have a prime factor less than or equal to $\ n\ $ , but upto $\ n=500\ $ , there is none.

Comment: How can you say that the chances are good, when you show an example with $n=605$ !

Comment: By the PNT, the “probability” of one of these numbers being prime is $\frac{1}{\ln\left(\left(9n\right)!+n!+1\right)}$. Wolfram|Alpha shows that the sum to infinity of this series is infinite. So in fact, we should *expect* infinitely many primes in this sequence. Unless some specific modular stuff is going on in the background, or something else.

Comment: How did you check for number up to 500? $4500!$ is a huge number!

Comment: @OlivierRoche with factordb

Comment: To the down- and closevoters : This questions meets all standards : Motivation, what I have done, and an exact description what I want.

Comment: @YvesDaoust URL gave another argument, but the probability to get a prime is even higher because of the lack of small factors.

Comment: I checked with pari/gp upto $\ n=570\ $ , no primes

Comment: Continued to $\ n=820\ $ without finding a prime.

Comment: @Peter Using Mathematica I checked everything up to $n=1000$ with no primes found

Comment: @Peter Update: No primes up to $n=1200$

Comment: what is a probable prime?

Comment: @mathworker21 See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probable_prime). Also, there are no primes of the given form up to $n=1400$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch why the heck is 'probable' in parentheses? that's a very important word

Comment: @mathworker21 Has been removed by someone else. The paranthesis were because some of the mentioned primes are proven primes . Since a prime of the desired form must be huge and it a primality proof won't be possible, I am content with a probable prime.

Comment: @math *probable prime* is a standard term in the factorization, primality testing community. It means a number that has passed one or more tests that all primes, and relatively few composites, pass.

Comment: Maybe, Peter, it would be better to explicitly indicate which are primes and which are probable primes.

Comment: @GerryMyerson OK, I thought this would not be necessary because it is only the motivation of the question.

Comment: Not much of a help but you can rule out $n$'s with $n+1$ a prime, since then $n+1 \mid (9n)!+n!+1$ by Wilson's theorem.

Comment: @Sil Thank you for pointing this out, although I have noticed this as well. We also can rule out $\ n\ $, such that $\ n!+1\ $ has a "small" factor, to be exact , smaller than $\ 9n\ $

Comment: @Peter "are respective the smallest  for which we get a prime" this is still false. ill remove downvote once problem is true

Comment: Please give us a context for this problem. Did it come from a number theory class, or did you just create it ex nihilo?

Comment: @BalancedTryteOperators It is just recreational mathematics.

Comment: I checked up to $n=5\ 000$ ($189\ 850$ digits) without finding any primes. After sieving up to $p=2^{32}$ there remain $5\ 428$ primes with $n < 20\ 000$. The expected number of primes left to find within this bound is approximately $0.2075$.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Although this doesn't answer your question, it might still be helpful:

Using Mathematica (and an *exhaustive* amount of computing power), I have checked every number $(9n)!+n!+1$ for $n\le 2000$ **with no prime found**.

Finding a prime now seems very hard. For example, if we were to model a number $n$ „being prime“ as a Bernoulli random variable with parameter $\frac{1}{\ln(n)}$ [albeit motivated by the prime number theorem, this is a *very* rough model, for instance one could do much better already by distinguishing even and odd numbers], and if we assume the Bernoullis to be independent for $2001\le n\le 3000$ [once again very rough], then the probability of at least one success in our model is $$1-\prod_{n=2001}^{3000}\left(1-\frac{1}{\ln\left(\left(9n\right)!+n!+1\right)}\right)\approx0.00499232.$$

If you nonetheless want to continue the search for primes, here is my Mathematica code (just replace STARTHERE and STOPHERE by the lower and upper bounds of $n$ to check):

```
SetSharedVariable[primes, checked]; primes = {}; checked = {};
Monitor[
 ParallelDo[
  If[! PrimeQ[n + 1],
   If[PrimeQ[(9 n)! + n! + 1], AppendTo[primes, n]]
  ];
  AppendTo[checked, n],
  {n, STARTHERE, STOPHERE}, Method -> "FinestGrained"
 ],
 {Sort[checked], primes}
]
```

EDIT: I have updated the source code because we can skip numbers $n$ for which $n+1$ is a prime number as pointed out in the comments by [Sil](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/290240/).

EDIT 2: Here is Python source code (sadly, the prime checking function of SymPy seems to be about ten times slower than that of Mathematica)

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from os import cpu_count

from sympy.ntheory import primetest
from math import factorial

import time

START = 200
STOP  = 200

def check(n):
    num = factorial(9*n)+factorial(n)+1
    if primetest.isprime(num):
        print("Found prime for", n)
        return n

if __name__ == '__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    with Pool(cpu_count()) as p:
        primes = p.map(check, list(range(START, STOP+1)))

    primes = [prime for prime in primes if prime]
    print("--- {} seconds ---".format(time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: This means that a prime of the desired form must have more than $\ 68\ 000\ $ digits. (+1) The probability to find a prime in the range $\ n\in\ [2000,3000]\ $ is higher because of the lack of small prime factors, but still chances that there is a prime in this range are small.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no Mathematica and I can neither run PFGW unter ubuntu. I do not expect further helpers or a better answer. Therefore, I accept it , although the probability estimate would have to be refined.

Comment: @Peter You can try https://www.wolframcloud.com/ However, the computation time there is limited and there is no parallelization  If you want I can try to translate my code into Python once I am at home

Comment: @Peter Also, I am not quite sure what a better probability estimate would be

Comment: We can consider that no prime factor below $n$ is possible which increases the chance to find a prime in some range. The expected number of primes would surely still be quite small however. But many of the numbers won't have a small factor, so many candidates will be left after a simple trial division sieve. That is a general problem of many prime projects.

Comment: If you have time, you can also search for primes of the form $$(3n)!+(2n)!+1$$ for positive integer $\ n\ $. I only found a proven prime for $\ n=46\ $ and apparently, there is no other upto $\ n=1200\ $

Comment: @Peter There are no primes of the form $$(3n)!+(2n)!+1$$ for $47\le n\le 1600$

Comment: @Peter Update: There are none for $47\le n\le 1800$. But I think we can attribute this to "bad luck"

Comment: @Peter Also, I have added a translation to Python which might be useful

Comment: @Peter Another prime for $(3n)!+(2n)!+1$ pops up at $n=5223$ (the resulting value is a proven prime, not just a probable one). Having said that, I don't think it is a good idea to use the comments section of an answer to a question to ask a completely different one; it makes it considerably more difficult to spot.

Comment: @PeterKošinár Actually I am genuinely amazed by the fact that you found this! How did you do it? Brute force (wow you must have had a lot of force in this case)? Also, how did you prove that this giant number is a prime?

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch Finding the number was indeed just a matter of brute force (as in, just a computer churning numbers for a few days, without any additional smarts). When it comes to proving its primality, there is a theorem (see for example [Theorem 2](https://primes.utm.edu/prove/prove3_1.html) at [The Prime Pages](https://primes.utm.edu/)) which allows us to do so if we can factor large portion of $(N-1)$, which is certainly divisible by $(2n)!$ in our case. Both the searching and primality proving were performed using a program named [OpenPFGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/).

Comment: @PeterKošinár Thank you for your search. I am surprised that the part $(2n)!$ which is much smaller than $(3n)!$ is enough to prove the primality. Maybe, you are right that I should not have posted this question in the comments, but I did not want to feed the notorious downvoters of any question or answer that has something to do with unusual primes. Not that I care of such downvotes, but I decided to avoid the reactions in this case.

Comment: @PeterKošinár By the way, did you also search for a prime of the form $\ (9n)!+n!+1\ $ ?

Comment: @Peter Yep, I tried to run a $(9n)!+n!+1$ search too... but without any success so far. On the other hand, I accidentally bumped into another value of $n$ for which $(3n)!+(2n)!+1$ is a (proven) prime: $n=8178$ :-)

Comment: @PeterKošinár Upto which limit did you check $(9n)!+n!+1$ ? The second prime you found has more than $97k$ digits - almost $100k$. Thank you for your search.

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not help:
$$(kn)!+n!+1=\left(\prod_{m=2}^k\binom{mn}{n}\right){n!}^k+n!+1=n!\left(\left(\prod_{m=2}^k\binom{mn}{n}\right){n!}^{k-1}+1\right)+1$$ which is nearly recursive in $k$ Just chiming in .